# Most famous statisticians

Tags: methodology, history

What are the most important statisticians, and what is it that made them famous?
(Reply just one scientist per answer please.)

Comment: Converted to community wiki.

Comment: what is community wiki?

Comment: @Mariana: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/432/what-is-community-wiki

Comment: @Mariana The idea is that pools and list-ofs are converted to a form in which they can be easily managed (due to lower rep req to edit) and voted up/down without hurting participants' reputation (votes on CW posts does not give/take reputation).

Comment: If it weren't CW it would have to be closed as subjective and argumentative!

Comment: Thank you very much for doing that, but I am sorry to tell you that I can not see anything i the first link.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Reverend [Thomas Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bayes) for discovering Bayes' theorem

Comment: But was he _really_ a statistician?

Comment: That's a tough one...when did statistics become a real field? Many of the fathers of stats were not statisticians.

Comment: I know my choice is kind of arbitrary, because many are important but this is my favourite one, and his method allowed me to do lots of things.

Comment: That this was selected indicates a biased prior.

Comment: Does one *discover* a theorem? Shouldn't it be *postulating* or *theorizing*?

Comment: Sigh.  I would have hoped that one could be an enthusiast of the Bayesian approach without actually believing that Bayes the man was the greatest statistician of all time.  Shouldn't we honor someone who contributed important work to its development, like, e.g., [Jaynes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Thompson_Jaynes)?

Comment: As I understand it, Thomas Bayes (ca 1701 to 1761) never published the theorem that has been attributed to him.  Richard Price, from Bayes writings, introduced it to the Royal Society two years after Baye's death which led to its posthumous publication in 1764.  There it essentially lay dormant until the principle was rediscovered, developed and applied by Pierre Simon Laplace around 1774.  But Laplace's formulation was so different that one "can discount that he had seen Baye's essay" (Stigler, The History of Statistics, Harvard University Press, 1986, 2003).

Comment: I assume that Bayes is rightly celebrated for the theorem, but it's a very simple theorem of elementary probability theory.  Bayes theorem is used outside of statistics, and within statistics, it's used outside of Bayesian statistics.  The idea that Bayes himself is a famous *statistician* seems quite wrong.

Answer (score 94):

[Ronald Fisher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher) for his fundamental contributions to the way we analyze data, whether it be the analysis of variance framework, maximum likelihood, permutation tests, or any number of other ground-breaking discoveries.

Comment: It's worth noting that Fisher is equally famous for his work as a biologist (evolutionary biology and agricultural science) as he is for his statistical work.

Comment: *Even today, I occasionally meet geneticists who ask me whether it is true that the great geneticist R. A. Fisher was also an important statistician*
-- Leonard Savage 
(Annals of Statistics, 1976 http://www.jstor.org/stable/2958221).

Comment: @Michael Lew: He certainly is. He managed to get over the supposed disconnection between Mendelian genetics and Darwinian evolution, among other accomplishments. http://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/coll/special//fisher/9.pdf

Comment: If you want to ask a tough question, ask who the second most famous statistician is. There's no doubt that Fisher is # 1. You may not like the man or some of his ideas, but he is undoubtedly the creator of Statistics as we know it today.

Comment: @Carlos "undoubtedly the creator" are you a member of FA (Fisher's Adorators) ? Anyway Gauss introduced least square almost a hundred year before Fisher was born, and Fisher as well as Gauss were inspired by a lot of other very inspired people... it is a long and laborious story and unfortunatly for those who like THX surround movies I don't really think it has its Guru.

Answer (score 57):

[John Tukey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tukey) for Fast Fourier Transforms, exploratory data analysis (EDA), box plots, projection pursuit, jackknife (along with Quenouille). Coined the words "software" and "bit".

Comment: wasnt it Shannon who coined "bit"

Comment: From Wikipedia "Claude E. Shannon first used the word bit in his seminal 1948 paper. He attributed its origin to John W. Tukey"

Answer (score 52):

[Karl Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Pearson) for his work on mathematical statistics.  Pearson correlation, Chi-square test, and principal components analysis are just a few of the incredibly important ideas that stem from his works.

Comment: I'm really surprised that Tukey is beating Pearson right now! :)

Comment: @neil Everybody loves boxplots. :)

Comment: @Bob: ;-) see also http://go.helms-net.de/stat/images/boxplots.gif

Answer (score 50):

[Carl Gauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss) for least squares estimation.

Answer (score 48):

[William Sealy Gosset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Sealy_Gosset) for Student's t-distribution and the statistically-driven improvement of beer.

Comment: Maybe not the most famous statistician, but when you put it like that, definitely the most important! ;o)

Comment: @ IanS - to be precise, he improved the quality of Guiness, which is a stout, not a beer (in case you hadn't noticed, I'm Irish).

Comment: A stout is a beer, by every reasonable definition of beer. Roasting barley does not transform the beverage into an entirely different type of beverage.

Answer (score 46):

[Bradley Efron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley_Efron) for the [Bootstrap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) - one of the most useful techniques in computational statistics.

Comment: A related question with a nice answer: [How did Efron imagine the bootstrap?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/92344/32036)

Comment: Brad Efron did a lot in addition to the bootstrap--- such as geometry of inference

Answer (score 41):

[Andrey Nikolayevich Kolmogorov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov), for putting probability theory on a rigorous mathematical footing. While he was a mathematician, not a statistician, undoubtedly his work is important in many branches of statistics.

Comment: +1 for Kolmogorov. Without him, a rigorous treatment of most fundamental statistical concepts would not be possible and therefore statistics not as reliable as they are now.

Comment: Amen. His Probability Axioms combined with Measure Theory (Émile Borel, Henri Lebesgue, Johann Radon and Maurice Fréchet) could be considered the most powerful analytical technique in applied mathematics, in my opinion.

Comment: Komolgorov should absolutely be first on any list of contributors to mathematical probability.  The implications of his contribution are so widespread as to be ... unmeasurable.  That makes his work foundational to statistics, but it doesn't make him a "famous statistician".  (Neither should developers of measure theory, such as Borel,  count as famous statisticians.)

Answer (score 38):

[Pierre-Simon Laplace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace) for work on fundamentals of (Bayesian) probability.

Comment: and the central limit theorem.

Comment: Not a famous statistician.

Comment: @Mars he perhaps isn't as famous as he should be, but we are still using techniques that he invented today and ironically he is arguably more responsible for Bayesianism that the Rev Bayes.

Answer (score 32):

[Francis Galton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Galton) for discovering statistical correlation and promoting regression.

Comment: +1 for Francis Galton played a very important role in giving importance to the concept of correlation. However, I found a bit strong the formulation "creating correlation". I would quote Galton itself: << "Co-relation or correlation of structure" is a phrase much used in biology, and not least in that branch of it which refers to heridity, and the idea is even more frequently present than the phrase; but I am not aware of any attempt to define it clearly >> In : "Co-relation and their Measurment" (see here http://galton.org/galton/index.html)

Comment: @robin: You could say that Galton did not create the idea of correlation, but did create the first statistical representation of it. Google "francis galton's account of the invention of correlation"

Comment: -1 In1884,Galton wrote:"Jews are specialized for a parasitical existence upon other nations,and that there is need of evidence that theyare capable of fulfilling thevaried duties ofa civilized nation by themselves."Karl Pearson,Galton's disciple and biographer,echoed this opinion 40years later during his attempt to prove the undesirability of Jewish immigration into Britain:"for such men as religion,social habits,or language keep asa caste apart,there should be no place.they will not be absorbed by,and at the same time strengthenthe existing population;they will develop into a parasitic race"

Comment: @IrishStat. Yup, a lot of the early statisticians were eugenists, including Pearson and Fisher. But, they were still great statisticians.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Fisher in this regard ?

Comment: @IrishStat: Fisher was the first president of the Cambridge University Eugenics Society, wrote for *Eugenics Review* and *Annals of Eugenics* from 1914 to 1947, and was appointed professor of eugenics at University College London in 1933.

Answer (score 32):

[George Box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_E._P._Box) for his work on time series, designed experiments and elucidating the iterative nature of scientific discovery (proposing and testing models).

Comment: While looking for other names in Wikipedia, I stumbled on the fact that Box was a son-in-law of Fisher's.

Comment: Don't forget the Box plot.

Comment: I presume @Hans Engler is joking, but either way Box did not invent the box plot. Tukey named the box plot, and re-invented a practice common in various fields.

Answer (score 30):

[Andrey Markov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Markov) for stochastic processes and markov chains.

Comment: was he a statistician? I mean, did he wrote things about estimation?

Comment: he was a mathematician that was very important to statistics. Half of the men on here lived before statistics was an "official" field of study .

Comment: good point ! I guess I meant that even before it was official, some mathematicians (like Gauss) concidered statistical problems while I don't really know if Markov did concider statistical problem himself.

Answer (score 29):

[Jerzy Neyman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerzy_Neyman) and [Egon Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.S._Pearson) for work on experimental design, hypothesis testing, confidence intervals, and the Neyman-Pearson lemma.

Comment: Kudos to Jerzy for "proving" storks bring babies illustrating the concomitant variable problem.

Answer (score 28):

How has [Sir David Roxbee Cox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cox_%28statistician%29) not been mentioned yet?

Some feats:  Cox proportional hazards models, experimental design, he did a lot of work on stochastic processes and binary data.  He also advised many students who went on to do great work (Hinkley, McCullagh, Little, Atkinson, etc.)

And the man was knighted!

Comment: +1 for Sir D.R. Cox, a great man indeed. He and co-autors wrote a number of excellent books which I believe inspired many researchers and applied statisticians around the world, and are major
contributions to modern statistics.

Answer (score 27):

[Leo Breiman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leo_Breiman) for CART, bagging, and random forests.

Comment: And probability.  Shannon-Macmillan-Breiman.

Answer (score 25):

[Harold Jeffreys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Jeffreys) for revival of Bayesian interpretation of probability.

Answer (score 24):

[Edwin Thompson Jaynes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Thompson_Jaynes) for work on objective Bayesian methods, particularly MaxEnt and transformation groups.

Comment: For me, he is the best statistical thinker ever.  And also one of the most interesting and distinctive writing styles I've seen.  Never seen anyone use the word "common sense" like he does!

Comment: Jaynes' book "Probability Theory" has no equal, in my opinion, for one who wishes a deep understanding the subject in practice.

Answer (score 23):

[Florence Nightingale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florence_Nightingale) for being "a true pioneer in the graphical representation of statistics" and developing the polar area diagram. Yes, *that* Florence Nightingale!

Comment: Nightingale did excellent work, but her originality is often exaggerated. Polar diagrams were used by several people before her, earlier in the 19th century.

Comment: This is what I explain to nursing students, to demonstrate to them that they should be interested in statistics. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 23):

[C.R. Rao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calyampudi_Radhakrishna_Rao) for the Rao–Blackwell theorem and the Cramer-Rao bound.

Answer (score 22):

[Blaise Pascal and Pierre de Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points) for creating the theory of probability and inventing the idea of expected value (1654) in order to solve a problem grounded in statistical observations (from gambling).

Answer (score 15):

[Roderick Little](http://sitemaker.umich.edu/rlittle/home) and [Donald Rubin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Rubin) for the contributions in Missing Data Analysis.

Comment: Don Rubin also had a hand in the EM algorithm and the development of causal inference.

Answer (score 13):

[W. Edwards Deming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Edwards_Deming) for promoting statistical process control

Answer (score 12):

[George Dantzig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dantzig) for the Simplex Method, and for being the student who mistook two open statistics problems that Neyman had written on the board for homework problems, and in his "ignorance" solving them. I'd vote for him just for the story.

Comment: This story is identical to one told about John Milnor.  In Milnor's case there's at least one paper (co-authored with his professor when Milnor was still an undergraduate) to give the story credence.  Have you ever found a reference to the paper(s) Dantzig wrote giving his solutions?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the first paper was with/by Neyman and the second result was enough to get Dantzig a co-authorship with Abraham Wald. No actual references given, though.

Comment: Thanks.  It is interesting how such a story can recur and how it might actually be true in both cases!

Comment: @whuber Yes, it is! My skept-o-meter says that the details of multiple stories may not be quite right, though. Perhaps both of them solved open problems, but maybe one of them knew the problem was open and the other mistook it for a homework problem. The stories would match in terms of "naive young student solves open problem, not having realized how hard it really was", but when the story became legend and someone told it as "some student ...", someone else chimed in, "oh, that was Dantzig", or "oh, that sounds like Milnor" and the stories converged.

Answer (score 9):

[Samuel S. Wilks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samuel_S._Wilks) was a leader in the development of mathematical statistics. He developed the [theorem on the distribution of the likelihood ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Distribution%3a_Wilks.27_theorem), a fundamental result that is used in a wide variety of situations.

He also helped found the Princeton statistics department, where he was Fred Mosteller's advisor, among others, and has a prestigious [ASA award](http://www.amstat.org/careers/samuelwilksaward.cfm) named after him.

Answer (score 9):

Abraham Wald (1902-1950) for introducing the concept of Wald-tests and for his fundamental work on statistical decision theory.

Answer (score 9):

[John Nelder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Nelder), for providing us the now omnipresent generalized linear model framework. By his approach of unifying various standard statistical models and its estimation method, the iteratively reweighted least squares method for ML, he gave us tools that we are using now in almost all applied and theoretical concepts that are related to exponential family models. Not to mention his contributions to optimization as the superb Nelder-Mead-Algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

[David Donoho](http://stat.stanford.edu/~donoho/) development of multiscale ideas in statistics, and a lot of theoretically justified while practically very efficient ideas in very high dimensional statistics, CHA: computational harmonic analysis,...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Did you guys know that he is working for a hedge fund now?

Answer (score 7):

[Lucien Le Cam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Le_Cam) for his contribution to mathematical statistics. (maybe Local asymptotic normality and contiguity made him famous)

Answer (score 7):

[Leland Wilkinson](http://www.cs.uic.edu/~wilkinson/) for his contribution to statistical graphics.

Comment: Should we add Hadley Wickham for making GoG possible in R?

Answer (score 7):

[Adolphe Quetelet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolphe_Quetelet) for his work on the "average man", and for pioneering the use of statistics in the social sciences.  Before him, statistics were largely confined to the physical sciences (astronomy, in particular).

Comment: hadn't heard of him before, but I'll check him out. Thanks for the intro!

Answer (score 6):

[Emanuel Parzen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Parzen) for kernel density estimation and reproducing kernel Hilbert space theory for stochastic processes.

Comment: I think Rosenblatt invented kde several years before Parzen.

Answer (score 6):

It's very difficult to add to the constellation of stars that are already listed, but for interest purposes I will throw in the *improbable* polymath [John Maynard Keynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Maynard_Keynes) who many would not realize published *A Treatise on Probability* (1921) that can be downloaded [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/32625); and whose work was quoted frequently by Harold Jeffreys (1939).

Keynes by all accounts helped to bring forward Bayesian statistics and in his treatise considered the most important principle to be the [Principle of Indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference).

According to Wikipedia, *The "Principle of insufficient reason" was renamed the "Principle of Indifference" by the economist John Maynard Keynes (1921), who was careful to note that it applies only when there is no knowledge indicating unequal probabilities.*

Answer (score 6):

Robert Gentleman and Ross Ihaka for being the two initiators of and later main contributors of R, see https://cran.r-project.org/doc/html/interface98-paper/paper_1.html

Comment: +1 R programming language has brought joy to Statistics in general.

Answer (score 6):

[William Cleveland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_S._Cleveland), for either coining or popularising the term 'data science', but more importantly for contributions to data visualisation including the popular 'dot plot', and contributions to nonparametric regression such as loess smoothing.

Answer (score 5):

Brian Ripley for contributions to spatial statistics, neural network from statistician point of view, and a lot of other contributions, not the least of them being a main contributor to the success of R!

Answer (score 4):

Vladimir Vapnik:

For his fundamental contributions to our understanding of machine learning, which allows computers to classify new data based on statistical models derived from earlier examples, and for his invention of widely used machine learning techniques.

Answer (score 4):

[Irving John Good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I._J._Good) for contributions, among others, to Bayesian Statistics. He learnt probability from Turing at Bletchley Park. Some of his ideas was mentioned at [What is the role of the logarithm in Shannon's entropy?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87182/what-is-the-role-of-the-logarithm-in-shannons-entropy/463828#463828)  which has references.

He was also a consultant for Kubrick at the famous film [2001: A Space Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_(film)).

Answer (score 3):

[Teuvo Kohonen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teuvo_Kohonen) for invention of the [Self-Organizing-Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Organizing_Map) (SOM).

Comment: and maybe also Bishop, Svensen and Williams for putting SOM on a clean probabilistic footing via the Generative Topographic Mapping.  (And I didn't down vote anything either...)

Comment: self-organizing precursors of Kohonen included Alan Turing (1952), Willshaw, Bunenman and Longuet-Higgens (1960s) and von der Malsburg (1973). (Didn't down vote anything either...)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to also add [William Gemmell Cochran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Gemmell_Cochran) who is well known for establishing (or directing studies at) some of the preeminent statistics departments such as at Iowa State University, Harvard, Cambridge, that educated hundreds of future statisticians.  His methods on Survey Sampling Techniques and Design and Analysis of Experiments are still widely used today.

Answer (score 2):

Bill James for his work in statistics that evaluate MLB player performance. His work spawned the term Sabermetics.  He has created numerous statistics that can be found throughout the baseball world.  His ideas stem from how to capture a player's overall impact on a game through run production (offense) and runs saved (defense).  His work has led to less emphaisis on statistics that have low correlation to run production (batting average) and more on OPS (on-base + slugging).  He works as an advisor to the Boston Red Sox and is credited to the World Series Championships in 2004 and 2007.  His work has influenced the book and upcoming feature film Moneyball.

Comment: What about Nate Silver then?

Answer (score 2):

If you judge based on the number of times their work is cited, [E. L. Kaplan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_L._Kaplan) and [Paul Meier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Meier_(statistician)) since their 1958 paper "Nonparametric Estimation from Incomplete Observations" is widely regarded as [the most cited paper in statistics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24083551_The_most-cited_statistical_papers).

Answer (score 1):

Joseph Hilbe (1944-), first president of the International Astrostatistics Association and author of over 10 books on statistical modeling, including popular texts on count models, logistic regression, generalized estimating equations (GEE), generalized linear models, and statistical methodology. Hilbe is an emeritus professor at the University of Hawaii and adjunct professor of statistics at Arizona State University.

Answer (score 1):

[John Kingman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Kingman) for Coalescent theory and his work on completely random measures

Answer (score 1):

[Harald Cramér](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Cram%C3%A9r)  was a swedish statistician, mathematician and actuary.  John Kingman described him as "one of the giants of statistical theory".

Among his first works was application of probability in number theory. His 1946 book *Mathematical Methods of Statistics* was very influential, in showing a place for mathematical rigour in statistics.  Most people will have heard about the [Cramér-Rao inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound).

Answer (score 0):

[Lotfi A. Zadeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotfi_A._Zadeh), who not only coined the terms "fuzzy set" and "fuzzy logic", but invented many of the accompanying fuzzy statistics (like the sigma count, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

[Jerome Harold Friedman](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome_H._Friedman) for his contributions on CART (jointly with Leo Breiman in 1984), gradient boosting machines and partial dependence plots. Plus being co-author of the book (ESL)...

Answer (score 0):

[Peter Bentler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_M._Bentler) has made significant contributions to the implementation (e.g., his software [EQS](https://mvsoft.com/eqs/)) and theory underlying structural equation modeling (SEM).