# The (logarithmic & ratio-based) laws of psychology/perception as a metaphor for statistical significance

Tags: statistical-significance, psychology

In the psychology of perception (psychophysics), for two stimuli to be just-discernible (just-noticeable difference, JND), the difference between their magnitudes (e.g. the pitch or the loudness of two tones) needs to be greater if their individual absolute values are high, a relationship known as the Weber-Fechner law.

Similarly, in numerical cognition (the psychology of numbers), it becomes increasingly difficult to discriminate among two numbers separated by a constant amount, as their absolute values increase (by the same amount).

In other words, the JND depends not (only) on the *difference* between the stimuli but (also) on their *ratio*.

It is tempting to consider whether Weber's law also applies to the statistical significance of the difference between two means, as depicted for instance in the plot below:

[image]

But is it not in fact the case that, when the relevant statistics are computed, e.g. independent samples t-test and its associated p-value, it turns out that it is only the *difference* between the means (plus, of course, the variance that goes into each one of them, and the respective sample sizes) and not their *ratio* that predicts the p-value that in turn tells us about the significance of the difference between them?

Comment: I'd argue that such comparison is too abstract to be meaningful...

Comment: I don't have any answer, but you may find it interesting (if you haven't already) to read [Chapter 4 of Jaynes' Probability Theory](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf). While the whole book is interesting, he makes a similar comparison between Weber's law and Bayesian evidence.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion Greg, thank you. Jaynes says: "When
probabilities approach one or zero, our intuition doesn’t work very well. Does the difference between the probability of 0.999 and 0.9999 mean a great deal to you? It certainly doesn’t to the writer. But after living with this for only a short while, the difference between evidence of plus 30 db and plus 40 db does have a clear meaning to us. It is now in a scale which our minds comprehend naturally. This is just another example of the Weber–Fechner law; intuitive human sensations tend to be logarithmic functions of the stimulus"

Comment: @z8080:  Long before Jaynes, CS Peirce observed the same! See my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87182/what-is-the-role-of-the-logarithm-in-shannons-entropy/463828#463828

Comment: @Greg:  See my other comment ..,.