# Relationship between KL divergence and entropy

Tags: optimization, likelihood, entropy, kullback-leibler, variational-bayes

In Bishop's [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2006/01/Bishop-Pattern-Recognition-and-Machine-Learning-2006.pdf), there is a small discussion in section 10.1.2 of the difference between minimizing $D_{KL}(p \:||\: q)$ and $D_{KL}(q \:||\: p)$ with respect to the parameters of $q$, where $p$ is a known distribution. Specifically, they state that minimizing $D_{KL}(p \:||\: q)$ results in a broad distribution for $q$ that averages across multiple modes of $p$ while minimizing $D_{KL}(q \:||\: p)$ results in a $q$ is concentrated on a single mode of $p$. Intuitively, I see averaging across multiple modes as resulting in a $q$ which has greater entropy than one which is concentrated on a single mode. The figure below from the book summarizes this:

[image]

However, this contradicts the mathematics since,
$$
D_{KL}(p \:||\: q) = H(p,q) - H(p) \tag{1}\label{eq:klpq}
$$
and
$$
D_{KL}(q \:||\: p) = H(q,p) - H(q) \tag{2}\label{eq:klqp}
$$
as given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Motivation). Therefore, mathematically, minimizing $D_{KL}(q \:||\: p)$ is accomplished by encouraging larger values for the entropy of $q$ while minimizing $D_{KL}(p \:||\: q)$ effectively ignores the entropy of $q$.

Shouldn't the entropy of $q$ be greater when minimizing $D_{KL}(q \:||\: p)$ than when minimizing $D_{KL}(p \:||\: q)$ (each w.r.t. parameters of $q$)?

Comment: Look at the citations in my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87182/what-is-the-role-of-the-logarithm-in-shannons-entropy/463828#463828

Comment: Your post isn't entirely clear: 1) Your definition of $\text{D}_\text{KL}$ seems to be inverted compared to the one used at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758.  Also, when you say minimize  $\text{D}_\text{KL}(p || q)$, is it with respect to $p$ or $q$?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I was using the definition given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Motivation). I meant minimizing with respect to parameters of $q$.

Comment: Can you please add that to the main post?

Answer (score 8):

I will reformulate using my answer at [Intuition on the Kullback-Leibler (KL) Divergence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758). Since I am a statistician, I am more comfortable with likelihoods than with entropies, but I also think that gives more intuition here. Now entropy $ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}} H(X) =-\sum_x p(x) \log p(x) =-\E_p \log p$. So entropy is simply the negative expected loglikelihood. Similarly, cross-entropy is the (negative) expected loglikelihood, but now **not** calculated  under itself "its own truth", but under some other distribution, some other truth. We can use this to express the divergences as 
$$
   \text{D}_\text{KL}(p || q) = \E_p \log p - \E_p \log q
\label{*} \tag{*}
$$ and 
$$
\text{D}_\text{KL}(q || p) = \E_q \log q - \E_q \log p \label{**} \tag{**}
$$ Using the interpretation from the above linked post, $\text{D}_\text{KL}(p || q)$ is the expectation under the alternative of the log likelihood ratio for testing $H_0\colon q$ against the alternative $p$. In your setting, $p$ is a known distribution, and we suppose it is multimodal. In case $\eqref{*}$, $q$ is the null distribution and the divergence is small for such $q$ which is difficult to reject against alternative $p$, when the expectation is calculated under $p$. But that means all the modes of $p$ will contribute to the expectation,so better that $q$ have some mass in all those modes. So this minimization must indeed give distributions that have some probability everywhere $p$ has it.

Then turn to $\eqref{**}$. Now $p$ is the null hypothesis and the divergence is small when it is difficult to reject $p$ against the alternative $q$, and the expectation is calculated under $q$. So in this case, if $q$ omits some of the modes of $p$, that does not matter, because the large likelihood ratio there does not contribute to the expectation!  So the conclusion in the book is indeed correct.

Another comment: In $\eqref{*}$, if the known distribution $p$ is the empirical data distribution, we find a model $q$ best approximating it, we get effectively maximum likelihood.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the KL divergence $D_{KL}(p||q)$ is synonymous with the [**relative** entropy](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597D/L03.pdf), relative entropy of $p$ with respect to $q$.

> Entropy then becomes the **self**‐information of a random variable. Mutual information is a special case of a more general quantity called relative entropy, which is a measure of the distance between two probability distributions.

Source: [Entropy, Relative Entropy and Mutual Information](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471200611.ch2)

Secondly, **the entropy is related to the relative entropy**, relative entropy of $p$ with respect to a uniform distribution.

> Intuitively, the entropy of a random variable X with a probability distribution $p(x)$ is related to how much $p(x)$ diverges from the uniform distribution on the support of $X$. The more $p(x)$ diverges the lesser its entropy and vice versa.

\begin{align}
H(X) &= \sum_{x\in X}p(x)\log \frac{1}{p(x)} \\
&=log|X| - \sum_{x\in X}p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{\frac{1}{|X|}} \\
&=\log|X|-D(p||uniform)
\end{align}

Source: section 1.2 of [COS597D: Information Theory in Computer Science](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall11/cos597D/L03.pdf)

Then your question(the title) can be rephrased into "the relationship between relative entropy of $p$ relative to $q$ and relative entropy of $q$ relative to uniform distribution". It's impossible that how $p$ diverges from $q$ relates to how $q$ diverges from a uniform distribution given that $p$ and $q$ can be any distribution pairs.

> Shouldn't the entropy of $q$ be greater when minimizing $D_{KL}(q \:||\: p)$ than when minimizing $D_{KL}(p \:||\: q)$ (each w.r.t. parameters of $q$)?

NO.

The two relative entropy just don't correlate two each other. The relative entropy of $q$ relative to a uniform distribution doesn't depend on which relative entropy you are minimizing(because $p$ can be varying).

Comment: +1 for the showing the relation $\log |X| - D(p||\text{uniform})$. It is nice that you cited the slides so that everyone can access it. Any chance you have a textbook recommendation as well?

Comment: @Galen Elements of Information Theory by Cover. Hope this helps.